# Swing thread communication

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am creating a small swing application which plots a set of points given in a file. Guidelines suggested me to invoke a new thread for the GUI, for which I used the following code.

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new View().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

One of the scenario in the application is to open a file (which is done using a `JFileChooser`).

```
private void openMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        //some heavy operations
    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }
}
```

There are some heavy operations that are needed to be done, before proceeding to plot the points.

My questions are, is it advisable to place heavy codes in the `GUI` thread ? Is it possible to send the file object to the main thread for processing and send the results to `GUI` thread ?

Please note that I have no idea about Java Threading API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `SwingWorker`
`SwingWorker` proposes a way to solve it by performing the time-consuming task on another background thread, keeping the GUI responsive during this time.

take a look at this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/SwingWorker_Example

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mkarg/archive/2010/01/03/did-you-know-swingworker-can-send-progress-status

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2003/jw-0606-swingworker.html

Comment: http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/SwingWorker_Example
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mkarg/archive/2010/01/03/did-you-know-swingworker-can-send-progress-status these two links were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the result of the long running task modifies a Swing component, you can use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). For more information, please see [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).